# Semantic Issue with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My code in my `.h` file is

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTask;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *buttonDone;
```

and the error shows up

`@synthesize` of 'weak' property is only allowed in `ARC` or `GC` mode

when I replace the weak with strong, the button doesn't work

I can't put it in ARC mode( it will destroy my project)

Anything I can Do?

Comment: `weak` doesn't mean anything under manual memory management. It's either `retain` or `assign` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `retain` or `assign` if you don't want to use `ARC`

**retain**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTask;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *buttonDone;
```

**assign**

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTask;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *buttonDone;
```

Comment: unsafe_unretained is the same as assign in MRC mode.

Comment: If the OP originally wanted `weak`, then `assign` should be used, not `retain`.

Comment: @user2102538 did you try `assign`?